# Распаковка .phar архива средствами Java

Tags: php, java

Возникла необходимость распаковать .phar архив средствами Java. В интернете ответов на этот вопрос не нашел. Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, какие-либо библиотеки (если, конечно, таковые имеются), либо другие способы осуществления этого.

Comment: Не дайте расширению вас смутить, это обычный zip-архив

Comment: phar это tar или bzip архив так и работайте с ним

Answer (score 1):

> Не дайте расширению вас смутить, это обычный zip-архив – Etki 2 дня назад

Не нашел файл с расширением .phar, (ОЧЕНЬ ЖАЛКО :( ) так-что попробовать код не смог, Однако проверил на .zip и даже на .docx.... -> переименуйте ваш фаил.phar в фил.zip и все будет ок

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.zip.*;

/**
 * Данный класс предоставляет методы для распаковки архива ZIP
 * @author Germes
 * @version 0.1.a
 */
public class Unpacking
{
    /**
     * Данный метод осуществляет распаковку архива ZIP
     * @param name_File_Zip данный параметр передаёт имя или путь к файлу архива ZIP
     */
    public static void unZip(String name_File_Zip)
    {
        // открываем файл архива ZIP
        File openFileZip = new File(name_File_Zip);
        // переменная потока чтения Zip
        ZipFile openZip;
        // Определяем папку для распаковки
        String name_folder_unpacking = name_File_Zip.replaceAll(".zip", "");
        // Создаём папку для распаковки
        if(new File(name_folder_unpacking).mkdir())
                    System.out.println(" Формирование папки для распаковки архив: " + name_folder_unpacking);
        try
        {
            openZip = new ZipFile(openFileZip);
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> elementZIP = openZip.entries();

            ZipEntry elementBuffer;
            while(elementZIP.hasMoreElements())
            {
                elementBuffer = elementZIP.nextElement();

                // если элемент массива равен NULL
                if(elementBuffer == null) break;

                // если элемент массива папка
                else if(elementBuffer.isDirectory())
                {
                    if(new File(name_folder_unpacking + "/" + elementBuffer.getName()).mkdir())
                                System.out.println(" Создаётся папка                        : " 
                                            + name_folder_unpacking + "/" + elementBuffer.getName());
                }

                // элемент архива удовлетворяет всем условиям
                else
                {
                    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(name_folder_unpacking + "/" + elementBuffer.getName(), "/");
                    String bufferString = token.nextToken();

                    while (true)
                    {
                        if (!token.hasMoreElements())
                        {
                            // открываем поток чтения
                            InputStream readElement = openZip.getInputStream(elementBuffer);
                            // открываем поток записи
                            FileOutputStream writeElement = new FileOutputStream(bufferString);
                            // записываем распакованный элемент в папку
                            write_Element_Zip(readElement, writeElement);
                            break;
                        }

                        // отработка нестандартных ситуаций
                        else
                        {
                            if(new File(bufferString).mkdir()) 
                                        System.out.println(" Создаётся папка                        : " + bufferString);

                            bufferString = bufferString.concat("/" + token.nextElement());
                            System.out.println(" Распаковка                             : " + bufferString);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // закрытие потока чтения ZIP
            openZip.close();
        }
        catch(ZipException eZIP)
        {
            System.out.println("Формат открываемого файла не ZIP");
        }
        catch(IOException eIO)
        {
            System.out.println("Проблемы с чтением открываемого файла ZIP " + eIO );
        }
        catch(NullPointerException eNUL)
        {
            System.out.println("Отсутствует читаемый элемент в ZIP");
        }
    }

    //Метод реализующий запись потока ввода в поток вывода
    private static void write_Element_Zip(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException
    {
        int bufferByte = in.read();
        while(bufferByte != -1)
        {
            out.write(bufferByte);
            bufferByte = in.read();
        }
        //Закрываем потоки ввода и вывода
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
}
```